# Returning All Indexes of an Array

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a very basic WinForms App that searches for the number of files in a specified folder that the user selects. When the folder is selected the number of files within this folder are specified in a text box. Part of my code is shown below:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
txbNumberOfFiles.Text = files.Length.ToString();
```

Now this works fine, it displays the number of files in the text box once they have all been found. However, what I want is the text box to display the indexes of the array as it grows in size. So it goes 1 then 2 then 3 etc. Then once processing is finished, the last number would be the total number of files found.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe a backroundworker could help.

Comment: Getting file names is a fast operation. You want to slow it down and process each file separately? And what is expected output? Do you need file names, or just number of files?

Comment: The only reason you might want to display an uptick of found files is for a much, MUCH slower operation such as a scan/search of many folders and involve some asynch processing. The snippet you're showing us will return very quickly and not give you "a chance" to show progress.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `foreach` with counter variable . This is one of the solutions but not best

```
        folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);

        int count = 1;
        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + count.ToString();
            count++;
        }
```

Comment: that will be very quick, and he will never see the file names

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
textboxControl.Text = String.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(1, files.Length));
```

For `files.Length` = 10 it will generate

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can use something like this:

First add a Timer:

```
Timer tm = new Timer(); // define in it class level,in the top of your code
```

In form Load set it properties:

```
tm.Enabled = true;
tm.Interval = 1000;
tm.Tick += timer1_Tick;
```

Handle Tick event:

```
 private int i = 0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = String.Format("File {0}: {1}", i+1, files[i]);
        i++;
        if (i == files.Length)
        {
            textBox1.Text == "Total Files: " + i;
            tm.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Then when you load your files start the timer:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
tm.Start();
```